Allow sudo to ALL users for a particular command
I want to allow all the users on a system to mount a disk named with users name.
At the same time I do not want to allow user A to be able to mount the disk of user B.
my disk name will be available at /dev/disk/by-id/user-disk-${USER}
Added the following in my sudoers file to no avail
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-id/user-disk-${SUDO_USER} /mnt/${SUDO_USER}
this works fine
testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-id/testuser /mnt/testuser
I tried creating a script that does the mount and allowing that script to be executed with sudo. This works fine.
I wanted to know if it is possible to use the variable expansion in the sudoers file itself instead of maintaining another script.

Not a solution, but shell scripts running as root via sudo (or setuid) carry a number of risks due to how easy they are to subvert / monkey with their behaviour (eg using -E to bring across environment variables).

I wonder if autofs (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-autofs) might solve the underlying problem you are trying to solve with the above question?

@SmilingDragon my use case is disk, it is not a NAS, hence I could not use autofs

Your method of creating a "trusted" shell script that automatically builds the command from environmental variables is the way to go.
Commands defined in sudo don't do environment variable expansion. With your example above, people can run this literal command (you'd have to escape the dollar sign or put it in single quotes):
/usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-id/user-disk-${SUDO_USER} /mnt/${SUDO_USER}

It only supports shell-style wildcards (globs). From the man page:

Wildcards
sudo allows shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters) to be used in host names, path names and command line arguments in the sudoers file. Wildcard matching is done via the glob(3) and fnmatch(3) functions as specified by IEEE Std 1003.1 (“POSIX.1”).
 *         Matches any set of zero or more characters (including white space).

 ?         Matches any single character (including white space).

 [...]     Matches any character in the specified range.

 [!...]    Matches any character not in the specified range.

 \x        For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’.  This is used to escape special characters such as: ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’, and ‘]’.



I do not see any reference for the sudoers file does not do variable expansion. I see in some places a script is given the sudo permission and the script is managed to have access only to root.

Note that users can be in more than one group.
Suppose all valid users were listed in one common group "users", then use the group name to do this:
%users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-id/testuser /mnt/testuser

using the group is just fine, I am interested in the variable expansion for the text 'testuser' it should be replaced by the invoking user's id. we get ${SUDO_USER} environment variable but it is not getting expanded in the command
